# Setting up event tracking with Google Analytics - is there an error in my approach?

Tags: jquery, joomla, google-analytics

I have a Joomla site, and have loaded Google Analytics via

```
<script type="text/javascript">var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

      </script>
```

In the Joomla file where download links are rendered, I have the following

```
<a title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($attachment->titleAttribute); ?>" href="<?php echo $attachment->link; ?>" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Click', 'Downloads','0']);"><?php echo $attachment->title; ?></a>
```

This results in urls such as

```
<a title="file.pdf" href="/index.php/products/someproduct/item/download/60_7372007fc87f36b939ebed0ab3be8e65" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Click', 'Downloads','0']);">Product</a>
```

But the event is not being created in GA. Do you see anything obvious that is going wrong? When a user goes to the page and clicks this link, a save file box appears, so I know the url itself is formatted fine, but just seems that the onclick event is not getting fed to GA and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone see anything clearly wrong in my implementation? For what it is worth, jquery is loaded, but I really can't imagine that that causes a problem.

thanks!

Comment: Your last parameter is wrong - event value is supposed to be an integer, not a string, so lose the quotes (value is optional in any case, so you do not need to set it at all).

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved the problem! Now if I could only figure out how to extract geographic info for the event...

Comment: Extract geographic data as in applying a secondary dimension to your Top Event report? Or as in sending a detected geolocation along with the event from your server to GA?

Comment: The second option. I think I figured it out. I created a goal for the event type, and now under Geo->Location I can choose the goal. But not a very convenient approach. Ideally I am trying to build a report that for each download, depicts the country.

Comment: Look into Custom Dimensions- you should set the dimension to be your custom geolocation and then send your event. Now in your Top Events report you can add a secondary dimension of your custom dimension. You could also trigger goals off of that too! You could even apply the custom dimension at the user scope so any other actions they take will be associated with that custom geolocation. Hope that helps!

Comment: You do not need to store a custom geolocation, you can simply got to customization and create a custom report either as a table with event dimensions and geo information, or even as a map overlay (select a metric, set your event or goal as a filter and select map overlay as visualization). In any case this has stopped to be a coding problem and should be a new question, this time at webmasters.stackexchange.com.